# "cov vs pp" problem

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, cardinal-arithmetic, pcf-theory

This is the problem $(\beta)$ of the section 14.7 in the "Analytical Guide" of the Shelah's book "Cardinal Arithmetic":

> $(\beta)$ Is $\operatorname{cov} ( \lambda , \lambda, \aleph_{1} , 2) =^{+} \operatorname{pp} ( \lambda )$ when $\operatorname{cf}( \lambda ) = \aleph_0$?

Is this problem still open?

We know that $\operatorname{cov} ( \lambda , \lambda, {(\operatorname{cf}(\lambda))}^{+} , 2) = \operatorname{pp} (\lambda )$ for every singular $\lambda$ such that $\lambda < \aleph_\lambda$ (see for instance the Claim 3.7(1) in the Chapter IX of the Shelah's book).

Can the following statement be a theorem in ZFC?

$\operatorname{cov} ( \lambda , \lambda, {(\operatorname{cf}(\lambda))}^{+} , 2) = \operatorname{pp} (\lambda )$ for every infinite cardinal $\lambda$ with $\operatorname{cf}( \lambda ) < \lambda = \aleph_{\lambda}$.

Answer (score 11):

Very much an open problem.  I've been sporadically blogging about aspects of this question over the past few years, mainly in an effort to pin down exactly what's known and what's still unknown.  There are some links to this work on my [website](http://www.ohio.edu/people/eisworth/).

With regard to your other question, the answer is yes under GCH, because both the covering number and the pp number must be equal to $\lambda^+$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your attention!

Yes, SSH ($\operatorname{pp} (\lambda) = \lambda^+$ for every singular $\lambda$) follows from GCH and from "$0^{\sharp}$ does not exist", and SSH implies that $\operatorname{cov} ( \lambda , \lambda, {(\operatorname{cf}(\lambda))}^{+} , 2) = \lambda^+$ for every singular $\lambda$.

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to address your revised question as soon as I get a little time.  First week of semester is always busy.

Comment: The link in this answer no longer works - here is at least a Wayback Machine snapshot: [main page](https://web.archive.org/web/20160323121324/http://www.ohio.edu/people/eisworth/) and [publications](https://web.archive.org/web/20160323123226/http://www.ohio.edu/people/eisworth/research/published.html).